# bind parameters does not work with dates

Tags: php, date, mysqli, bindparam

i am using a prepared statement for a select on a period table:

```
$query_period = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM period WHERE date_start<= '?' AND date_end >='?'");
$query_period->bind_param('ss',$date_start,$date_end);
```

and the execution gives a parameter number error:

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): **Number of variables doesn't match** number of parameters in prepared statement

the error does not occur when i remove the " around the ? like this:

```
$query_period = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM period WHERE date_start<= ? AND date_end >=?");
```

but also the query does not match the correct result.
how can i do this?

because if go like this:

```
$query_period = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM period WHERE date_start<= '$date_start' AND date_end >='$date_end'");
```

it all works fine

Answer (score 0):

Bind parameters **does work** with dates.

There is **absolutely no difference** between a query with a placeholder and a query with the actual value. Neither for a date nor for any other data type.

Therefore, your problem is coming from whatever else direction. The input data, the data in database - you know. The sooner you realize that and stop barking the wrong tree, the sooner you will have your problem solved.

Comment: i know there should be no difference. but i dont understand how the problem can be in the data itself. i'm not executing the query the error is on the bind... the other problem is i barked more than one tree but without any nice outcome

Comment: You know, it happens to all of us. Sometimes our code doesn't work. It's your job to debug it and find the cause. But you can be sure that prepared statement is not one. So it helps you to narrow the possibilities.

Comment: Wait. you said the error on the bind? **So you are still using that version with quotes?!**

Comment: ok so, the version with quotes cause the bind not to recognize the parameters, and when i don't use the quotes the problem is in the data? ok i'll get deeper in to it thanks